# Django 4 problem: user can't login but admin yes

Tags: python, django, web

I continue my progression with Django 4. But I have a new problem. my login code does not work, yet I followed the doc (I believe).

The problem is at this level in my view.py.

```
user=auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

it returns none

and only admin can login, no the user created.

*Could someone explain to me why the code does not work. Did I forget something?*

Here is my html code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<section class="section-conten padding-y" style="min-height:84vh">
    <div class="card mx-auto" style="max-width: 380px; margin-top:100px;">
      <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title mb-4">Sign in</h4>
                {% include 'includes/alerts.html' %}
      <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
             <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
          </div> <!-- form-group// -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          </div> <!-- form-group// -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <a href="#" class="float-right">Forgot password?</a>

          </div> <!-- form-group form-check .// -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Login  </button>
          </div> <!-- form-group// -->
      </form>
      </div> <!-- card-body.// -->
    </div> <!-- card .// -->

     <p class="text-center mt-4">Don't have account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign up</a></p>
     <br><br>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

and my view code

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            # messages.success(request, 'Registration successful.')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials.')
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

This is how I create the users:

```
register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = email.split("@")[0]
            user = Account.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=username, password=password)
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Registration successful.')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

Comment: Do you have a user with that login and password in the database?

Comment: How do you create your users? Maybe the password not hashed properly.

Comment: the code works. But I realize superadmin can login except site users who can't login.
This is how I create the users:

Comment: I found why only superusers can login. At the level of the class Account(AbstractBaseUser) it was necessary to replace is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False) by the value is_active.BooleanField(default=True).